# Excel Lookup and sum multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, lookup

```
A          B       C        D           D             E          F
DEForage201 DE  Deutschland 201 Perennial Ryegrass  Forage      789951
DEForage201 DE  Germany     201 Perennial Ryegrass  Forage      5617026
```

In the list above (starting in column `A` which is an ID line compiled by column `B`, `F` and `D`) I want to lookup and get the sum of the rightmost column.

Currently I am using vlookup and look for the ID line in column `A`, until I noticed that the country names in column `C` would differ during the list which is why I am having identical ID lines in column `A` and currently only get the first value.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I'm unsure what you want, but could `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` do the job?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad this data is total sales in quantity, I then have another table with total market size in quantity where I have also made a similar ID line and want to calculate market share. Does it make sense?

Comment: Do you want total sales (using `SUMIF`) / total market size (again using `SUMIF`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad and BigBen

Thank you both; I initially didn't think the sumif would do me any help (currently suffering from severe sleep deprivation due to newborn twins!), but as you both suggested it I tried it again and it actually did the job, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a way to view the sum of column F for each unique combination of columns A through E, a Pivot Table might be what you're looking for. You can select columns A through E as the "rows" for the pivot table, and sum of column F for the values. Adjust the report layout in the Pivot Table Design tab to get it to look the way you want.